# Debezium, Kafka-connect : updates to postgres are not showing up as messages, only inserts are

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am using the command :
    # bin/connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone.properties config/debezium-config.properties

My debezium-config.properties is :

```
name=publications-connector
database.hostname=localhost
database.port=5432
database.user=andy
database.password=postgres
database.dbname=postgres
database.server.name=dbserver1
table.whitelist=public.publications
```

In Postgres, I have a table called publications

When I insert a new record into the publications table, I can see that my consumer shows the new message in json format.

However when I update an existing record into the publications, no new message is published to the topic and hence nothing to consume.

How can I fix this ?

Also, I would like to add another table 'comments' to my database. What changes do I need to make to the debezium-config.properties file or anywhere else to have those messages be published to its own topic ?

I see the following logs from the console :
WARN: no values found for table 'public.publications' from update message at 'source_info[server=dbserver1'db='postgres', .... schema=public, table=publications]'; skipping record (io.debezium.connector.postgres.RecordsStreamProducer:333)

Thanks,

Comment: Can you, please, clarify why you haven't set `database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers` and `database.history.kafka.topic` properties in your configuration file? And to what topic all your messages are published?

Answer (score 3):

After some detailed reading into many debezium topics, i was able to solve this by setting the REPLICA IDENTITY to FULL. Once I did this, on updates I was able to see the update messages and consume them.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is this:
If a table does not have a primary key, the connector does not emit UPDATE or DELETE events for that table. For a table without a primary key, the connector emits only create events. Typically, a table without a primary key is used for appending messages to the end of the table, which means that UPDATE and DELETE events are not useful.
[reference resources](https://gitter.im/debezium/user?at=5f6dd5b56e85e0058c5495b6)